# Whonix 13.0.0.1.4 and 14.0.0.2.6 fails to boot

Tags: boot, kvm, qemu, libvirt, whonix

I've tried installing and booting both Whonix 13.0.0.1.4 and Whonix14.0.0.2.6, downloaded and verified from Whonix's onion mirror. In both cases and with both VMs I got this same result. A black screen with "Booting from Hard Disk... Boot failed: not a bootable disk. No bootable device."

To install them I followed this guide (https://www.whonix.org/wiki/KVM), the only thing I've done differently is to download alternative packages for libvirt-bin, as suggested by apt:

```
[sudo] password for thoreau: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package libvirt-bin is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  libvirt-daemon-system libvirt-dev libvirt-clients

E: Package 'libvirt-bin' has no installation candidate
thoreau@Thoreau:~/Installers/Whonix$
```

And that's it. I'm stuck and don't even know what seems to be the problem. If there's any more information that I could provide, please ask.

Comment: Btw you are not supposed to use the developers-only version 14.0.0.2.6. You are not supposed to directly go to download.whonix.org. Go through https://www.whonix.org/wiki/Download.

Comment: I asking at https://forums.whonix.org/c/kvm instead. This is a KVM installation issue. Not really a Whonix issue. You need to show what commands you typed to install it and then might have to go back and forth several times to debug it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had the same problem yesterday and got a solution. The problem lies with the repositories that you have. Im sure your running Kali-Rolling as I am as well. You will need to change your repo sources.list so that you can acquire the package you need and then removing that source for security purposes.

```
#deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie main
#deb-src http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie main
#deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie-updates main
#deb-src http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie-updates main
#deb http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main
#deb-src http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main
```